# Resizing an Arrow shape

Tags: java, shapes, jmonkeyengine

I have an arrow:

```
Arrow ballArrow =  new Arrow("Ball Arrow", 2, 0.175f);
```

And I want to resize it to make it longer whenever a key is pressed (say Key_5).

Which method would I call to resize it as when i'm calling .setLength() and .setWidth() they keep getting slashed out and i'm not sure what that means.

BTW i'm using jMonkeyEngine 2 not 3.

Comment: Slashed out usually means deprecated and that you should use a newer version of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Arrow API](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/doc/com/jme/scene/shape/Arrow.html), `setLength` and `setWidth` are deprecated. To do the resizing, you should be doing:

```
Arrow ballArrow = new Arrow("Ball Arrow", 2, 0.175f);
....
float newLength = (somevalue);
float newWidth = (somevalue);
ballArrow.updateGeometry(newLength, newWidth);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I think that's it, but whenever I call it (i.e. I press Key_7) the arrow dissapears. Do I have to reattach it to the rootNode everytime I update it?